# UIScrollView autolayout - vertical scroll only

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

`UIScrollView` is a little special in the way it interprets auto layout constraints, as geometry of the subviews fills its `contentSize` as opposed to `frame`/`bounds`. Apple has a nice write up on the matter here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

The problem I'm facing is when I try in place multiline labels into the `scrollView`.

An example constrain looks like this:

```
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[image(==imageWidth)]-15-[captionLabel]|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: metrics, views: views))
```

I'm not showing additional subviews that are handled by other `scrollView.addConstraints()` calls which take up more vertical space.

Ideally, I want both elements to fit horizontally within the screen, and have the `captionLabel` break into multiple lines as necessary. Instead, the whole text is rendered into a single line and the `scrollView` sets its `contentSize` to accommodate the larger width.

What options are there to solve with auto layout?

*Edit*: Not too happy about nesting more contentViews, so I ended up setting the desired width of the label in a separate constraint, and updating it in `viewWillTransitionToSize`. In my case, a whole list of similar "rows" of labels in used, and only the first one has width set through a calculated constraint, the rest are set to be equal to the first.

Comment: what about the hierarchy of your view, and the constraints of your scroll view ?

Answer (score 3):

First your view hierarchy should looks like this:

the most important is that you have only one child in your scroll view it will act as a content view.

[image: hierarchy]

The constraints :

ScrollView  = 4 constraints from edges to the main view with 0 spacing

ContentView = 4 constraints from edges to the ScrollView with 0 spacing

**And to avoid horizontal scrolling**

add a constraint of equal width between ContentView and Main view (not ScrollView)

now add content to your content view.  Use Auto Layout, like you normally would. Don't forget to set 0 as number of lines for your label add the top, right, left bottom constraints of the label.

[image: UILabel]

The result should be like mine :

[image: Scroll]

More information: [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you (i hope understand good the question), but if you only want scroll Vertical, you can add this in your implementation:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Vertical Only ** If you have several scrolling objects detect by Tag
   if (scrollView.tag == 100)  {
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    offset.x = 0;
    scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a storyboard solution, you can set the constraint "Equal Widths" twice: between your UIScrollView and its Superview, and between your UILabel and your UIScrollView